# Bash command option clarification bash -ex

Tags: linux

could you please explain to me what exactly this shell command do?
It is quite difficoult to retrive the description of this -ex option.

sh #!/bin/bash -ex

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are in fact two options, `bash -e -x`

Comment: For me, it just starts a new `sh` process in the current shell. The shebang (#!) is ignored b/c of the `#` char, making it a comment.
Is that line coming from a shell script file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you're invoking new bash shell with -e and -x shell options

See shell options here: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

`-e   errexit Abort script at first error, when a command exits with non-zero status (except in until or while loops, if-tests, list constructs)`

`-x   xtrace  Similar to -v, but expands commands`

since -x is similar to -v:

`-v   verbose Print each command to stdout before executing it`

So it's actually dropping to next level shell:

```
$ echo $SHLVL
1
$ sh #!/bin/bash -ex
$ echo $SHLVL
2
```

in which in this level 2 shell, option -e and -x is activated